# Weird jQuery error

Tags: jquery

I was going along minding my jQuery business, when all of a sudden, I tried to do this:

```
var myVariable = 'some-id-here';
$('#' + myVariable).addClass('some-class');
```

**Everything went fine and dandy until I closed my browser**. After I reopened the page, jQuery threw this weird error:

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

I was able to replace the second line with this and have it work, but I am curious why the first part didn't work after I closed and reopened my browser.

```
    $(document.getElementById(myVariable)).addClass('current');
```

Comment: What is the value of myVariable when it fails?

Comment: Can you reproduce this? Are you 1000% sure that is the line in question? Is `myVariable` declared literally in the way you show above?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only reason why you might get that error is because the variable evaluated to an empty string, in effect causing you to call `$('#')`

Comment: pinusnegra: '16-bean-soup'

Pekka: Yep, that was the line. Removing it stopped the areas. And yeah, it is declared via a `var` statement, albeit in a loop. Though, throughout the entire loop it was declared each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like when you are defining `myVariable`, there is a `#` and the beginning of the id.  This will also cause the exact error you are getting when you are using this as your selector -

```
$('##some-id-here').addClass('some-class');
```

If this is the issue, it would explain why using this instead does work: `$(document.getElementById(myVariable)).addClass('current');`

I'm not sure why closing the browser would affect this at all.  Maybe you made a change to your html that seemed to only be reflected when you reopened your browser?

Comment: Ah, yep. That must be it. The hash tag was in the string already. I guess `document.getElementById()` handles the hash okay. Still not sure about the browser-restart thing, but the double-hash tag is it.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#')` throws *"Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #"* in jQuery. So the problem is almost certainly that `myVariable` is empty..

Comment: I thought so too, but I `console.log()`ged it out, and it definitely had a value. It's a head-scratcher.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem using a 2-line example similar to the one you pasted in your question? (I'm guessing not)

Comment: I can't seem to do the reduced test case, but the weird thing isn't the error - it's that the error is NOT being thrown no matter how many times I try, until I restart my browser.

Answer (score 0):

If `myVariable` is not empty this should work without a problem even if the element with that ID does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the code somewhere else? Some lines down?